# How to take latest AMI always while scaling ASG?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using ASG for my application and I am attaching running instance to create ASG

Now the main problem is, Whenever new instance via ASG gets created it does not replicate the EC2 Instance attached to it so I cannot take updated or point in time binaries available on that running instance.

I get a fresh blank AMI to work which won't work for me.

Is there any way that I can replicate or I can use the attached instance as a base image in ASG while scaling out

Comment: Have you read through : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-walk-patch-windows-ami-autoscaling.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response